# Using defaultdict to handle dynamic insertion to key if not present

Tags: python

From another thread i came to know that to generate a custom dictionary where the keys are assigned dynamically, we can use collections's defaultdict instead of setdefault.

I;m trying to use that where in i have a list of node and each node will have a handle and cfg_str.

I wrote the code as below:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

custom_dict = defaultdict(list)

node = ['TERM1','TERM2','L2','S1','S2','TERM3']


for node in node:
    if re.search(r'TERM', node, re.I):
        custom_dict[node] = 'test'      --> this works.
        custom_dict[node]['handle'] = 'handle value'  --> this doesn;t work
        custom_dict[node]['cfg_str'] = {}     ---> This does not work

print(custom_dict)
```

am I missing anything here?

Comment: I think you want to use a `dict` as default instead of `list`.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Is this what you want ? You are using defaultdict(list), the value is list type, so you can not use it as dict.

`for node in node:
    if re.search(r'TERM', node, re.I):
        custom_dict[node] = {}
        custom_dict[node]['handle'] = 'handle value'  
        custom_dict[node]['cfg_str'] = {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need `defaultdict(dict)`.

**Ex:**

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

custom_dict = defaultdict(dict)

node = ['TERM1','TERM2','L2','S1','S2','TERM3']


for node in node:
    if re.search(r'TERM', node, re.I):
        custom_dict[node] = {'handle': 'handle value', 'cfg_str': {}}

print(custom_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'TERM3': {'cfg_str': {}, 'handle': 'handle value'}, 'TERM2': {'cfg_str': {}, 'handle': 'handle value'}, 'TERM1': {'cfg_str': {}, 'handle': 'handle value'}})
```

Comment: THanks Rakesh.. That works.. but One final question, Can;t I assign like this?          custom_dict[node]['cfg_str'][key] = 'value' .  -> This throws a key error...

Comment: You can include that line after `custom_dict[node] = {'handle': 'handle value', 'cfg_str': {}}`...................... ex: `custom_dict[node] = {'handle': 'handle value', 'cfg_str': {}}
        custom_dict[node]['cfg_str']["key"] = 'value'`

Comment: can we use this if key is also derived dynamically? in my case  key = 'vlan ' + str(vlan) , custom_dict[node]['vlan_cfg_str']["key"] = cfg_str . ->> This still throws the key error

Comment: `key = 'vlan ' + str("vlan")
        custom_dict[node] = {'handle': 'handle value', 'cfg_str': {}, 'vlan_cfg_str': {key: "cfg_str"}}` ?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn;t clear.  The above retains the last value only.. I want output to be something like this..custom_dict[node] = {'handle':'handle value', 'vlan_cfg_str': {vlan2:'cfg_str1',vlan3:'cfg_str2'}

Comment: This actually works.. But was just wondering if there was a better way to do things? vlan_conf_dict[key] = cfg_str

            custom_vlan_conf_dict[node] = {'handle': node_dict[node]['handle'], 'vlan_cfg_str': vlan_conf_dict}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your expected output is. But you can build dicts dynamically using the get method too look for keys and set defaults if absent.

```
foo = {}
nodes = ['TERM1','TERM2','L2','S1','S2','TERM3']
for node in nodes:
    if 'TERM' in node:
        foo[node] = foo.get(node, dict(handle = 'handle value',\
                                       cfg_str = {}))
```

foo is now:

```
{'TERM1': {'handle': 'handle value', 'cfg_str': {}},
 'TERM2': {'handle': 'handle value', 'cfg_str': {}},
 'TERM3': {'handle': 'handle value', 'cfg_str': {}}}
```